# Adverb "already"

Tags: grammar, tenses, adverbs, adverb-position

I have got a question about the adverb "already". Where should we put it in the sentence? Is "already" put after a subject and auxiliary verb but before predicate verb in the sentence? May we also put "alredy" at the end of the one?

For example: 
- He has already finished his homework
- He has finished his work already - Would it be correct?

And how is it used with the Present Perfect Progressive

"He has been already sitting there for two hours" or "He has been sitting there fot two hours already" Which sentence will be correct?

"has been" it is auxiliary verb, right?

Could you point out any other mistakes if i did.

Comment: *To make mistakes* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

"Correct/Incorrect", with parenthetical notes showing connotations.

Correct:

> He has already finished his homework

(He's quick.)

> He has finished his work already

(He's quicker than expected.)

> He has been sitting there for two hours already

(He's either determined, or very comfortable.)

Incorrect:

> He has *been already sitting* there for two hours

Correction:

> He has already been sitting there for two hours

(He's been left waiting too long.)